# Fragment does not display when select from navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have three fragments in my activity. I am using `Recyclerview` to display them. I wanted to make groupings of my fragment, like when A is selected in navigation drawer fragment 1 and 2 will display, using viewpager. And this works fine.

But when I select fragment B it does not display. And fragment B is not in the grouping.

Please help me out.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener{




Toolbar toolbar;
SharedPreferences savedPreferences;
private static Context mContext;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;





@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
    displayView(0);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    displayView(position);
}

private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new TabFragment();
            break;

        case 1:
            fragment = new MoviesFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();



    }
}}
```

In this case `MoviesFragment` is not displaying. When i select MoviesFragment from navigation drawer, only a blank white screen appears.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Solved it!**

The problem was not on MainActivity, it was the MoviesFragment itself. I just added an empty constructor and it worked.